# Export simple transform animation with FBX?

Tags: animation, .fbx

I guess I'm doing something wrong. I have simple transform animations on a bunch of objects (no joints used. Only rotate and translate keyframes). And when I save it to FBX, only one object remains the animation on it while the other stays static. I know I can save simple transform animation to fbx. I did it with Maya a few years ago. But now I can not achieve the same result with the Blender. Any thought?